# Facing an issue "Could not find class [org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.JdbcConfiguration] in spring-boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a code base which works perfectly on one of my machine but fails to run on another. While I am able to gather all dependencies without any issues I am getting error while running the main program.

While I am not able to copy paste the issue since its in RDP, please find below the stack trace. Any solutions would be of great help to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: did you add spring-data-jpa dependency in the pom.xml

Comment: @AnishB. I have added `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.2.6.RELEASE` and `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.6.RELEASE` as a part of my dependencies.

Comment: Only one dependency is enough. Remove org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc:2.2.6.RELEASE from the pom.xml. Try again to compile.

Comment: @AnishB. Can you please reply to the question. I just want to record the answer. Because its working. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all other dependencies related to `spring-boot-starter-jpa` in **pom.xml**.

Add only one dependency below. That's enough.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version> <!-- as mentioned (but optional if used at the parent level)-->
</dependency>
```

That's all.